# create a member with named by a string

Tags: c#, string, class

Obviously you can't create a member of a class like this

```
string name = "member-";
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    classname name+i.toString() = new classname();
}
```

I don't understand why and is there a good workaround?

What If I need to create several members?

Comment: I would ask you why you feel you need to do that? There are many ways of achieving similar results using other features of C# (collections and `dynamic` most relevantly.)

Comment: Seems like an array or something similar is what you're looking for.

Comment: User should generate own levels and for this, I need them to create a class for each room, so I want to let them name the instance of the object. Also, how should I create several instances in a loop?

Comment: An array doesn't got all the features a class got and is more "ugly" to use imho.

Comment: @Liam, so use a List instead of array.

Comment: But if you compare a list to a class a class just've got more features and is easier. No workaround? Maybe I should consider other things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the perfect case to use a `Dictionary<string, classname>`:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, SomeClassName>();

var name = "member-";

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    dictionary[name+i.ToString()] = new SomeClassName();
}
```

Comment: An array doesn't got all the features a class got and is more "ugly" to use imho.

Comment: @Liam: I don't know why exactly you say that. An array _is_ a class. What is ugly about it? If you are naming veriables `member1`, `member2`, `member3`, etc., why wouldn't you just call them `member[0]`, `member[1]`, `member[2]`?

Comment: Because the array has to be multidimensional and should store objects, strings, integers and much more.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to create 5 `classname` objects and keep them in order, a simple Array will do the trick. If you don't know how many you want ahead of time, use a `List<classname>` instead.

```
classname[] myClasses = new classname[5];
for(int i = 0; i < myClasses.Length; i++)
{
    myClasses[i] = new classname();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can come pretty close with the ExpandoObject in C# 4.0 as shown below. [Here is good MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx) on using them.

```
string name = "member-";
dynamic classname = new ExpandoObject();
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
  dynamic newmember = new ExpandoObject();
  classname[name+i.toString()] = newmember;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you don't use reflection to get a list of class names in an assembly/assemblies?

You can choose between the fully qualified name and the simple name. Then, you can format the string accordingly.

Comment: Is "I've got no idea how to use it" a good answer? Can you explain it a bit further? I'm going to sneak into the documentation.

Comment: @Liam Schnell, let's say SomeClass is a class. You would have some code var myClass = new SomeClass(); Then you could simply call myClass.GetType().Name. Of course, you would have to have the instance first in this scenario. Instead, you could reference the assembly. There is a method exposed by Assembly that will give you a list of classes.